# MariaDB Querying a join table but display a name from another table

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a table:

**macroregions_list**

| id_macroreg | name_macroreg |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Northern Italy |
| 2 | Central Italy |
| 3 | Southern Italy |

and another join table (where id_region is a foreign key to a 'Regions' table and id_macroregion is a foreign key to the previous table):

**macroregions_join**

| id_macroregion | id_region |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |

Ideally, when querying I would like to see something like:

```
Site | Region_name | name_macroreg | ...
```

While I am just able to see (correctly) the macroregion id using this code:

```sql
SELECT 
    id_macroregion AS 'Macroregion',
    -- a bunch of fields correctly displaying, but what I need is:
    name_macroreg
FROM plant_remains
-- Joining sample ID from plant_remains table to the main table (site_list)
INNER JOIN site_list ON plant_remains.uuid = site_list.bot
Inner JOIN macroregions_join mj on r.region_id = mj.id_region
```

I have no clue how to do this, my only guess is creating a table where each sample id is assigned the macroregion id.

Comment: Add a further join to `macroregions_list` and include the column in the query

Comment: I tried, but it prints a list like this:
# Sample 1 | Northern Italy
# Sample 1 | Southern Italy
# Sample 1 | Central Italy
and it does it for every sample

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it, thank you for the suggestion!

```
INNER JOIN macroregions_join mj on r.region_id = mj.id_region
INNER JOIN macroregions_list on mj.id_macroregion = macroregions_list.id_macroreg
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant :)